# Auto function must be defined before it is used

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

Say we have two member functions:

- public foo()
- private bar()

We want to call bar() in foo():

```
> cat test.cpp
class a
{
public:
    auto foo()
    {
        auto a = bar();
    }
private:
    auto bar()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
> g++ test.cpp -std=c++14
test.cpp:6:12: error: function 'bar' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
            auto a = bar();
                     ^
test.cpp:9:7: note: 'bar' declared here
    auto bar()
         ^
```

Does that mean I have to defined the **private bar() before the public foo()** to get through the compilation?

But I'm used to defining **public members before private ones**...

Will the parser be improved to allow calling `auto function()` before its definition?

Comment: What is your question? Are you saying it doesn't work? And the parser doesn't have anything to do with your code compiling.

Comment: that's very unlikely, because in order to determine the type of auto function, you have to parse the whole body first, which may contains other auto function, resulting very complicated compilation process

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I've modified my question to be more clear : D Feel free to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

The Standard says that (section 7.1.6.4):

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.

This rule helps prevent circularly-dependent types.

For example, what should happen if `foo`'s return type should be inferred in some manner depending on the local variable `a`, and `bar`'s return type involves a call to `foo()`?  Perhaps there are many different choices of type that would be completely consistent.... the compiler has no way of choosing one.  So, it requires that the return type be deduced (by seeing the return statement inside the function body) before it is needed.